# python ошибка SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

ошибка при простеньком коде

```
a = input("ведите слово")
print(a)
```

Comment: Почему у вас `input` и `print` в одной строке?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev потому что движок сайта игнорирует переносы строк

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.